# JMeter Regular Expression Not Handling String with Variable and '$'

Tags: regex, jmeter

Version: 3.0

I want to use a variable to parse a response that includes a '$'

```
${__V(${Variable})}\)</a></span><!-- R_PAGE_POSITION\$(..?)
```

This is not bringing back a match, but does if I either replace the variable with a value e.g.

```
12345\)</a></span><!-- R_CLASS_NAME\$(..?)
```

Or omit from the dollar sign onwards:

```
${__V(${Variable})}\)</a></span><!-- R_PAGE_POSITION
```

This suggests that there is some issue between the Variable syntax and the dollar sign that means they cannot co-exist.

Anyone experience a similar issue?

Comment: What if you escape `$` several times? `\\\$`? `\\$`?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that worked. I'd tried that directly in the response window and also in 'The Regex Coach' desktop app, and it hadn't worked.  It feels more like a bug, but I can move on now!

Comment: So, `${__V(${Variable})}\)</a></span><!-- R_PAGE_POSITION\\$(..?)` worked, didn't it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should add it as an answer.

Comment: @Mattje: Please precise: do you mean your response contains a literal dollar symbol, and you wanted to match it?

Comment: Correct. The $ was in the https response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **double backslash** here:

```
${__V(${Variable})}\)</a></span><!-- R_PAGE_POSITION\\$(..?)
                                                    ^^
```

That way, you let JMeter know that it is not a variable marker inside a JMeter expression (the first backslash), and that it is not the end-of-string anchor (the second backslash).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that worked. I'd tried that directly in the response window and also in 'The Regex Coach' desktop app, and it hadn't worked. It feels more like a bug, but I can move on now!